# getEventTime() in S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord vs LastModified for S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Sry I am new to AWS and I am confused with event trigger.

Is it possible that the LastModified of a object is not equal to getEventTime() considering it has subscribers which triggers when a new object is inserted.

If yes then why should it be the case since event-notification should be triggered only when the object is inserted so getEventTime() being equal to lastModified should make more sense?

Note: by getEvenTime() mean

```
S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord notification;
notification.getEventTime()
```

Comment: Technically the event time could be different if e.g. s3 has a hickup, stores the file but some internal system is backlogged for a fraction of a second, etc. If you **really** need guarantees about this I suggest you talk to the AWS support but they are unlikely to offer such specific reassurances.

Comment: Yess you are right Thanks mate!! A network latency may also change their timings I suppose then.